# Защита памяти при сегментной организации

Tags: ос, уязвимости, ассемблер

Приветствую.

Есть такая штука, как переполнение буффера: мы затираем адрес возврата в стеке на какой-то другой, по которому расположены инструкции, которые мы хотим выполнить. И скорее всего на адрес, который принадлежит сегменту стека (ну или кучи). Почему процессор, когда EIP указывает на адрес не из сегмента кода, не паникует и не выдает ошибку сегментации? Разве это не отслеживается флагами в дескрипторе сегментов?

[Википедия](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8) говорит, что такой защиты нет, но тогда возникает разумный вопрос, почему?

Comment: Потому что. Всё это дополнительное усложнение и удорожание процессора и ОС (да и снижение скорости). Кому это надо? Не пишите таких программ. Или пишите для процессоров гарвардской архитектуры, такое там просто невозможно.

Comment: Хороший вопрос. 

Надо конечно уточнить, что речь идет о x86 и не plain модели памяти. IMHO (но могу **сильно ошибаться**) в Linux используется защита памяти с атрибутами доступа (rwx) в таблице страниц MMU. Такой переход там должен вызвать ошибку, если не включен режим трассировки.

Обычно стек "портят" эмулируя вызов (реально возврат  на точку входа) существующей функции с нужными параметрами .

Comment: Я просто читаю сейчас http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/4833854/
Я не могу запустить даже первый "учебный" эксплоит, потому что база стека оказывается каждый раз в рандомном месте =( Кто-нибудь может подсказать, что с этим делать? :)

Comment: А что такое первый "учебный" эксплойт? Или сначала надо найти книгу, прочитать, а потом ответить? Тогда ждите, когда найдётся прочитавший этот кондуит и потрудится ответить. И ещё насчёт "срыва стека". К концу 90х годов злые программеры провели диверсионную акцию -- существенно ограничили возможности таких эксплойтов. В частности в программах для сети были ликвидированы как класс всякие strcat, strcpy и прочие strlen.

Comment: А strlen чем не угодил? strcat и strcpy - понятно, они не учитывают размер буфера.

Comment: Ну во-первых за давностью лет мог и перепутать, а во-вторых можно и защиту памяти словить, если повезёт. А желательность такого результата вызывает сомнения.

Comment: Нет никакой разницы, что за эксплойт. Там просто буффер, который переполняется и переписывает адрес возврата в стеке. Проблема в том, что каждый раз, когда запускаешь приложение, esp указывает в абсолютно разные места, соответственно адрес возврата угадать очень проблематично. А в книге не говорится о такой проблеме, она не очень новая, может с этим связано...

Comment: А, ну ясно. Есть ковёр-самолёт, но его моль поела.

Comment: Ок.

    int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
    {
        char buffer[500];
        printf("ESP:%x\n",buffer);
        strcpy(buffer, argv[1]);
        return 0;
    }

Каждый раз выводит разные значения для ESP, соответственно я не могу угадать адрес возврата.

Comment: Какой ужас? А если параметры запуска не менять, то всё равно меняет число, названное вами ESP? Или не меняет. Ну хотя бы длину параметра. Задаёте параметры разной длины, получается разный указатель стека на момент вызова main и, соответственно разный адрес buffer, который и выводится под именем ESP

Comment: Ну, капитан капитану рознь, знаете ли...

timramone@timramone:~/hacking$ ./1_1 a

ESP:bfecc3cc

timramone@timramone:~/hacking$ ./1_1 a

ESP:bf83708c

timramone@timramone:~/hacking$ ./1_1 a

ESP:bf8b633c

Comment: А зачем угадывать адрес возврата ? В данном случае он д.б. (void \*)&argc - sizeof(void \*);

Comment: Вы предлагаете в "уязвимом приложении" подправить адрес возврата? :D Его нужно знать до того, как приложение будет запущено) Но пока я вижу способа этого сделать, раз он каждый раз разный.

Comment: Относительные адреса переменных в стеке будут одинаковыми, хотя при разных запусках стек программы будет начинаться с разных абсолютных (конечно же виртуальных) адресов. 

-

Не знаю, что Вы хотите сломать (или починить ?), но вот адреса функций (они в сегменте text) при всех запусках будут одинаковыми.  

-

Кстати, адрес возврата в 64-bit CPU будет в другом месте (лень искать).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По поводу дискуссии, развернувшейся в комментариях (о случайном расположении стека в памяти), можно почитать про [Address Space Layout Randomization](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Space_Layout_Randomization). По поводу возможности или невозможности исполнения памяти мне было интересно почитать о [PaX](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/PaX). Случайно наткнулся на статью Касперски [Переполнение буфера на системах с неисполняемым стеком](http://www.insidepro.com/kk/063/063r.shtml), теперь знаю много умных слов :)